# How to read eclipse default key binding values which are in General-Keys-Keys Preference page

Tags: eclipse, preferences, key-bindings

I am using below code to get the updated preferences which are existed in workbench.prefs file.

```java
private  String nodeValue = "org.eclipse.ui.commands";

IPreferenceStore store = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
String updatedKeyString = store.getString(nodeValue);
```

But now I need to get default values for key binding's which are in General-Keys-Keys preference page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current key bindings from the binding service:

```java
IBindingService bindingService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(IBindingService.class);

Binding [] bindings = bindingService.getBindings();
```

Comment: IBindingService bindingService = (IBindingService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(IBindingService.class);
bindingService.getBestActiveBindingFormattedFor(CMDID);

I tried with above code, still i am getting null value.

Comment: That is used in several places in the Eclipse code so it does work. Check that you have the correct command id and that some binding is actual active for the command - not all commands are bound to a key.

Comment: If i update the binding value in keys preference page for particular command, can i get the updated binding value by using above code.

Comment: Because i am not getting key binding value after updation. And also if i press restore default's from preferences also i am not any key binding value.

Comment: The 'active' binding depends on what window, editor or dialog is currently active. You should probably be using the other methods of the service that don't just report active bindings.

Comment: How do i activate my key binding. I am using context id: org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window for key binding

Comment: Your question asked how to get the key bindings - I have answered that. Ask a new question if you have a new question.